# For Loop to Extract Vector Objects from Dataframe Column Headers

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe `df` with 50 columns, and I would like to generate vector objects for each column name, with the length of the dataframe rows.

My code throws out an error:

```
for i in ((1:ncol(df)) {
  colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))
  return (colnames(df)[i])
}
```

The error:

> > for i in ((1:ncol(df)) { Error: unexpected symbol in "for i"
> >       colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))
> >     Error in colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df)) :
> >     object 'i' not found
> >       return (colnames(df)[i]) Error: object 'i' not found
> >     } Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

P.S. Some of the columns in my dataframe are nested lists, just in case this affects the operation.

Comment: Could you please show an example of your `df`?, Is not clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Answer (score 1):

for(i in (1:ncol(df)))<----- parenthesis in wrong place

Comment: Oh, thanks for catching that. I corrected it, but here's the new error:

Comment: > for i in ((1:ncol(df))) {
Error: unexpected symbol in "for i"
>   colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))
Warning message:
In colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   return (colnames(df)[i])
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: @Susie it is saying that your created vector is no the same length as the original one, which is a warning and won't shut down your program. Second of all, format it this way ------  for (i in (1:ncol(df))) {
  colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))
  return (colnames(df)[i])
}

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df))
  return (colnames(df)[i])
}
```

I'm gonna guess that you want the number of entries in each column. Normally, in a dataframe, every column has the same number of rows. But you have list columns, so you want to calculate how long they are, unnested?

```
lapply(df, function(x) length(c(x, recursive=TRUE) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I got this warning: Warning message:
In colnames(df)[i] <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length  -- Any idea what to do? (sorry I'm newbie to R!)

Answer (score 0):

Making the same assumption than @Alex P and saying than his `lapply` solution is always more efficient than a `for` loop in R. If you still want to use a `for` loop, this is an option:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df$b <- list(1:1, 1:2, 1:3)

l<-list(NULL)
for (i in colnames(df)){
    p <- length(unlist(df[,i]))
    l[[i]] = p
}
```